# push key by int from kotlin to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

Firstly I'm sorry for my bad language and I hope you will understand me.

I want to push integer key to firebase by kotlin but I can't because I can't give a variable name with type int.

you can show the picture to understand me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phm3m.png)

if I want to change quantity to 0 not "0" (The type of int) how can I do that? I push data from my android app by class (object) , but I can't give the variable name of int ( just 0 without anything else ).

I ask that because I can do that in swift because I can push data to firebase by array of type Any. Is there anything like that in kotlin ? I test somethings like Map but it's not working the app give me error and don't push the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvscX.png)

Thank you for read and I'm sorry again for my bad language.

Comment: Try `val key = "0".toInt()`. Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html

Comment: Why do you say "I can't give a variable name with type int."? In your database both properties are numbers?